# How to ask Pytest to run a specific test in a python script?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

If I have multiple tests running in a script, e.g.:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    ("6*9", 42),
])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected

@pytest.mark.parametrize('test_input,expected', [
        (1,1),
        (2,2),
        (2,3),
        ])
def test_equal(test_input,expected):
    assert test_input == expected


if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    Test Zone!
    '''
    #executing the tests
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

How can I use the last line `pytest.main([__file__])` to run one of the tests at a time instead of running all of them at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `pytest.main()` acts like calling pytest from the command line according to the pytest [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code). You can pass in commands and arguments to this, allowing you to use the [-k](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests) [flag](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#using-k-expr-to-select-tests-based-on-their-name) to specify tests via a keyword expression:

```
pytest.main(["-k", "test_func"])
```

You can also you specify tests via [node id](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests):

```
pytest.main(["test_mod.py::test_func"])
```